# kmod dependency failure

Tags: upgrade, package-management, kernel

I am a novice. I built Linux 4.4 Ubuntu kernel on my test box. Total 13 files were generated but I am using 4 only.

```
linux-headers-4.4.0-59_4.4.0-59.80_all.deb
linux-headers-4.4.0-59-generic_4.4.0-59.80_amd64.deb
linux-image-4.4.0-59-generic_4.4.0-59.80_amd64.deb
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-59-generic_4.4.0-59.80_amd64.deb
```

I tried to upgrade ubuntu 3.13 kernel to 4.4 using these 4 pkgs only. 
But it failed on `kmod` dependency. While installing `kmod` using `apt-get`, I got following error on 3.13 machine:

```
$ sudo apt-get install kmod
Reading package lists... 
Done 
Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done 
Package kmod is not available but is referred to by another package. 
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source.
```

I tried `sudo apt-get update` but no luck.

Could you please help me fix it?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install -f` . I suspect the problem predates and is unrelated to your attempt at kernel upgrade.

Comment: `kmod` is available in Ubuntu repos. The error message means that you either are using some other distro, or you have no internet connection, or something else.

Comment: Most likely you are using an EoL version, etc.